# How to pass raw parameter using jsoup

Tags: java, post, jsoup

I want to call an API which just accepts raw data when you send requests using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

My code looks like this:

```
Document res = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        .data("name", "test", "room", "bedroom")
        .post();
```

But I know the above code is not right for passing raw data.

Can anybody tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use `HttpUrlConnection` to post the raw data to the website, and fetch the response as a String. Some Example, post data:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = new URL("http://somesite.com/").openConnection();
String str =  "some string goes here";  //use a String for our raw data
byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");  //byte array with raw data
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( outputInBytes );
```

Getting response as String:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

To parse with Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
```